# Ubuntu and Ruby version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have Ruby versions 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 on Ubuntu.

How do I get the system to register Ruby 1.9.1 when using `ruby -v`?

ruby is at /usr/bin/ruby
ruby1.9.1 is at /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

Comment: shouldn't this be on superuser?

Comment: @Dian: The text editor question should be (and surely already is), but configuring programming tools can be appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using rvm to manage multiple versions of Ruby. At first I was a bit skeptical about it, but once installed and configured, I found it works perfectly. I can now flip between 1.8.7, 1.9.2, and JRuby-1.5.1 and the paths change automatically.

Comment: Hi Mark,

I really want to install RVM. Can you help me out with post installation steps. 

In particular, not sure how to do this:

 "The first time you install RVM, you must put the following line into your profile at the very end, after all path loads etc:

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

what do I have to type in the terminal. My text editor is gedit.

Comment: I'd edit your .bashrc. From the terminal, "gksudo gedit ~/.bashrc" and add the line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

An ubuntu-like way could also be using "update-alternatives" as described [here](http://titusd.co.uk/2010/02/22/handling-multiple-versions-of-ruby)
Using RVM might save you a headache or two though :)

As for the texteditor: just use gedit and enable a few of its plugins

Answer (score 0):

`alias ruby='ruby1.9'` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

find ruby in your path.  Either change your PATH variable to direct through the Ruby 1.9 executable (assuming different directories) or create a symbolic  link of "ruby" to the versiuon you want.

The alias solution above will work, but only when your envuironment 8is sourced into the shell.  The link method works anywhere in a UNIX-like system.

Lert's assume you have the executables in `/usr/bin`.  This means that there is something like

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby1.9
```

What you need is to

1. rename /usr/bin/ruby as /usr/bin/ruby1.8.7
2. Write a short shell script selectRuby that takes an argument, and

   - if it's 8, execute `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.8.7 /usr/bin/ruby`
   - if 9, execute `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1,9 /usr/bin/ruby`

Ideally, you might want to have a default that sets one version or the other.

This script would, by necessity, have to be run through `sudo`.  If you don't want to, or cant, then set up your own `bin` directory at, say, `~/bin` and have a script that links ruby to `/usr/bin/ruby` or `/usr/bin/ruby1.9` as desired.  Make sure your bin is before the more global bins in your path and you'll be set.

Comment: i'm a complete newbie, please show how, thanks.

Comment: IN fact rvm more or less does what I suggested. I didn't realize there was a tool.

Okay,. your profile is a file named `.profile` in your home directory.  Use the `ls -a` commands, and you should see it.  Simply type that in verbatim at the end of the file, or if you don't have a .profile, create it and add that line.

What it really says, btw, is essentially "test if $HOME/.rvm/scipts/rvm exists and has contents, and if so, read that file into this shell as if it had been typed at the commend line.

Comment: You might have a look at sopme of the bash tutorials, like this one: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) instead of [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to install the lastest Ruby version in Ubuntu. It's simple and easier.

There is a good Digital Ocean example here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04